# Структурное описание компонента LUT5 на основе компонента LUT4

Tags: vhdl

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно описать структурно компонент LUT5 на основе компонента LUT4, проблема именно в правильном маппинге портов.

```
Entity LUT5 is
  Port(
    A,B,C,D,E : in std_logic;
    Z         : out std_logic;
  );
End LUT5;

Architecture Behaviour of LUT5 is
Component LUT4
  Port(
    A,B,C,D : in std_logic;
    Z       : out std_logic;
  );
End Component;
Begin
    ??????
End
End Architecture
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здравствуйте.
Вот картинка для примера LUT6 на базе двух LUT5.
[image: LUT6 из двух LUT5]